# How to send and receive data from ASP.NET server to Android

Tags: asp.net-web-api, androidhttpclient

I want to make a Biometric e-voting system.A voter register and cast vote through android app and all other activities are handled in asp.net server.here i want to know how send and receive data from ASP.NET server to Android

Answer (score 0):

Simply put:

Set up RESTful API in ASP.NET server. And in your Android app, consume it with Java (native app) or JavaScript (html app).

Answer (score 0):

Just create an ASP.net Web API project, create Web API controllers and write methods in it and call it from your Java code in Android.

Here's a sample which could be useful to understand what to do:

http://hintdesk.com/how-to-call-asp-net-web-api-service-from-android/